# How the correct way to change the actual view controller? On loaded view parent, presented and presentingViewController are null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios6, parentviewcontroller

I have the following structure on my iOS iPad app:

- RootViewController: Login

  - @property UITabbar *main (which is loaded after login with success);

On `appDelegate` I have two properties: window and login. On the first one I load the `UIWindow` and on other `LoginViewController (UIViewController)`. And set Login as RootViewController.

On Login I have a property named "main" typed as `MainController` (extends `UITabbarController`).

After the successfull login I use the code above to load main:

```
[_main setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentViewController:_main animated:YES completion:nil];
```

MainController was loaded in the viewDidLoad method. I have two points:

I need to set self as delegate of MainController?

This is the begin of my MainController viewDidLoad method:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setDelegate:self];
NSLog(@"Parent view controller is: %@", [self parentViewController]);
NSLog(@"Presented view controller is: %@", [self presentedViewController]);
NSLog(@"Presenting view controller is: %@", [self presentingViewController]);
```

The log of this is:

```
2013-01-20 21:23:53.180 MyApp[6304:11303] Parent view controller is: (null)
2013-01-20 21:23:53.181 MyApp[6304:11303] Presented view controller is: (null)
2013-01-20 21:23:53.182 MyApp[6304:11303] Presenting view controller is: (null)
```

Am I using the correct way to present a viewController? Or to show a view after I click on a button or login?
What is missing? Am I using correctly the view hierarchy?

Exists the need of a property to contain the controller which will be presented?

I appreciate since now!

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the code for the app delegate and and the other controllers yourself? If that's the case then because you haven't posted the rest of your code all I can say is to initialize all your view controllers.

```
YourViewControllerNameHere = [[ViewControllerType alloc] init];
```

or if you have a nib/xib/storyboard file then

```
    YourViewControllerNameHere = [[ViewControllerType alloc] initWithNibName:youInterfaceFileNameHereWithoutFileType bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Alex, i was initialized them. They are correctly loading and appearing, they just haven`t a parentViewController defined when they`re running.